# Having problems with react-sticky when used with routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-sticky

I'm using [react-sticky](https://github.com/captivationsoftware/react-sticky) and react-router in an app.

My routing is set up as follows

```
<StickyContainer>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={ContainerA} />
            <Route path="/containerb" component={ContainerB} />
            <Route path="/containerc/:id" component={ContainerC} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
</StickyContainer>
```

`<App />` contains a sticky AppBar. `<Container C />` contains another sticky bar that is stuck below the main bar.

This all works fine if I browse directly to `/containerc/1`, or refresh when on that page.

However, if I use a navigation link on `<ContainerA />` (for example) to go to `/containerc/1` the stickiness is broken.

It appears that using the SPA routing is not updating something that react-sticky requires.

Has anyone experienced this and found a fix?

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Did you ever find a workaround or solution?